# Is there any significance of lacustrine gastropoda fossils regarding paleoenviroment interpretation?

Tags: sedimentology, paleontology, fossils

How to interpret lots of gastropoda fossils seen in lacustrine marls? Do they indicate any paleoenvironment conditions? Depth, temperature, chemistry, ph?

Answer (score 2):

Shell stable isotopes, for oxygen and carbon reveals, if the gastropoda had lived in brackish, lacustrine or palustrine environment.

For discussion please see paper below.

Latal, C., Piller, W. E., & Harzhauser, M. (2004). Palaeoenvironmental reconstructions by stable isotopes of Middle Miocene gastropods of the Central Paratethys. Palaeogeography, Palaeoclimatology, Palaeoecology, 211(1-2), 157-169.

Answer (score 1):

Fossil preservation in  lacustrine marls is fairly common so it is really not that indicative of anything. Species might be used for wider correlation, but that's about it.